# Is this a good Sanitization function?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sanitization

Just want to say for all of my previous questions, thanks for helping me out with a few issues. Of course I'm a noob but learning is key.

I'm making a function that sanitizes the input before it gets submitted into the query to make sure it is secure. These are a few questions just from my last thread as well as some new questions. This question is directed to people who are really good with keeping inputs sanitized and secure.

This is how I do all of my queries.

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE data = ?");
$query ->execute(array($data));
```

And in mainly "insert" queries or any other type of query I do it like this.

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table ( data ) VALUES ( :data )";
$query ->execute(array(':data'=>$data));
```

I usually use this method for queries that require inserting tons of data. My question is, does either way work? I don't have anything binded because I have this sanitization function that I made.

```
function sanitize($type, $input) { 
if ($type == "email") { $input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); }
if ($type == "int") { $input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); }
if ($type == "float") { $input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT); }
if ($type == "string") {
    $input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    
    //$input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED); 
    $input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
    $input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); 
    $input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);
    //$input = filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); 
}
return $input;
```

}

My question is, is this the best way of using this sanitization function? Is there a better way of going about this? Like I said, security is my biggest concern with making projects and I don't want to risk having anything bad happen so I'd rather optimize security before I move on with the projects I am making.

And my final question is, what is the best way of doing CSRF tokens? I tried a script from I believe OWASP but a few of my friends claimed it has a few vulnerabilities so I don't want to use it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Prepared statements are good enough against SQL injection attacks. Is your sanitization function is supposed to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: When you insert into a database table, you want to ensure that no SQL injection can occur. That's why we use PDO and prepared statements. This is where your job with sanitizing stuff **stops**. The next step is pulling data out, working with it and ultimately - showing it to end-user. This is where you would want to protect against unwanted HTML and potential XSS. Therefore, do not make your own pre-insert sanitization functions - you can't make a better one that the one that PDO provides.

Comment: True but, PDO requires binding input to prevent it. I don't like relying on something that does the work for me, you know? I don't know how to explain.

Comment: It's not so much that it's good to have a concise and clear user sanitation its that with PDO and binds you don't have to think about it at all. Your sanitation may be clear to you and handle all the possibilities for this project, but may need to be customized for each project. Binding is the swiss knife of sanitation.

Comment: All the above comments are pretty good to be individual answers. Any reasons why they are just comments and not extended to become an answer?

Comment: So what you're saying is that you don't want to use a **proven** system dedicated to safe database interaction which is concise, short and interoperable and you prefer using some botched method you put together in a few seconds? How's that make any sense? How can you use convoluted code that's **not** proven, **not** tested, not interoperable and it's even longer and most likely slower than what PDO offers you? Be smart and use the right tool for the job. PDO is that tool, not the function you created. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, is this the best way of using this sanitization function?

This is a good way to perform sanitization. All sanitization methods will improve over time.

> Is there a better way of going about this?

If it is a web application that is providing you user input, you may want to guide the user on the UI with your expectations (e.g.  (Enter apartment number, if applicable. Otherwise, leave it blank)).

JavaScript can be used to enforce certain behavior.

When the data arrives to your PHP script, beyond the sanitation process also analyze whether the data is between X and Y length. For example, if customer is entering age, check that the age is in a valid limit.

If it is a string, and you prefer not to have any offensive tags, use `strip_tags` to remove them. Perform encoding/decoding/escaping of certain characters - think of using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, `htmlspecialchars`.

Additionally, if there are multiple insert statements running in one shot, use stored routines. Use transactions, regardless of routines. Rollback unless all the transactions complete as you desire.

Instead of using `select * from ...`, select required columns. It is possible that certain results, where only 2-3 columns are needed, may speed up dramatically if there is a covering index.

If your app uses `system`, `exec` etc., utilizing `escapeshellargs`/`escapeshellcmd` will be useful.

When displaying information on UI, ensure that relevant fields are displayed with `htmlspecialchars` in order to reduce/eliminate the chances of XSS. Also think of using `urlencode`/`json_encode` as necessary.

Take a look at http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Cross-Site-Request-Forgery-%28CSRF%29-Attacks-in-PHP that showcases, with examples, ways to prevent CSRF attacks.

Comments to your questions are all nice thoughts you should consider, and importantly - you have taken a step in the right direction already - so good for you!

Comment: "When the data arrives to your PHP script, beyond the sanitation process also analyze whether the data is between X and Y length. For example, if customer is entering age, check that the age is in a valid limit." 

I already do this, this is something I make sure I have when I use forms. :D

Comment: Excellent. You have already covered good ground on securing your application, and it is good to see devs like you focusing on app security.

Comment: Yes, I have very little knowledge of Security... I know the "tools" for security but don't know how to properly utilize it so it is right. :P Also thank you for supplying the "wikihow" about the CSRF. Very helpful! :)